# ckeditor formatting looks not good after copy and paste from ms word

Tags: php, html, css, drupal, ckeditor

I have DRUPAL website.I am using ck-editor but when user copy data with images from ms-word and paste into ck-editor then formatting not retains/maintains like ms word and after submit preview looks not good.In ms word file, client have data with images.
Suggest me which editor is good for copy and paste from ms word to editor.I want editor which retains formatting position like ms word.

Answer (score 1):

Did you do a regular copy-paste? CKEditor has a "Paste from Word" button that will take out most (all?) of the worst Word formatting and leave the rest. Edit the toolbar to remove the other paste buttons and your users can always use Paste from Word.

You can configure your toolbar like this.

```
config.toolbar = [   
    .....,
    { name: 'clipboard', items: [ 'Cut', 'Copy', 'Paste', 'PasteFromWord', ..... ] },
    .....
];
```

Comment: added an example. hope its ok